# Jest configuration to fix "Jest encountered an unexpected token" for import/export

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I would like to run the following test with Jest. I have no babel-config or jest-config yet. How can I configure jest to use ES6 features like import/export?

index.js:

```
export const add = (a, b) => a + b;
```

index.test.js

```
import { add } from '.';

describe('add', () => {
  it('adds a + b', () => {
    expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it works just like described in the docs at: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel

> To use Babel, install required dependencies via yarn:
>
> ```
> yarn add --dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env
> ```
>
> Configure Babel to target your current version of Node by creating a
>   babel.config.js file in the root of your project:
>
> ```
> // babel.config.js
> module.exports = {
>   presets: [
>     [
>       '@babel/preset-env',
>       {
>         targets: {
>           node: 'current',
>         },
>       },
>     ],
>   ],
> };
> ```

**Note:** Jest needs to have the same major version as the babel-jest package. I had Jest v23 and babel-jest v24 which lead to misguiding error messages.